# Guard let dictionary unwrap failing

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, guard, let

I've been trying to extract some data from a dictionary. There should be 5 values. The first code snippet fails, only populating the `scheduleForCurrentDay` with 1 value, whereas the second snippet works, getting all 5. Can anyone explain why the first one doesn't work? I'm guessing it's something to do with the dictionary being copied but I'm not really sure.

```
    // Fails; only gets one value
    private var categories = [StudyCategory]() {
        didSet {
            let c = categories
            for subject in c {
                guard let target = subject.quota[currentDayComponent] else { continue }
                scheduleForCurrentDay[subject.title] = target
            }
        }
    }

    // Succeeds; gets all 5 values
    private var categories = [StudyCategory]() {
        didSet {
            let c = categories
            var schedule = [String:Double]()
            for subject in c {
                schedule[subject.title] = subject.quota[currentDayComponent]
            }
            scheduleForCurrentDay = schedule
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I could not reproduce this in a playground.